# Firebase dependency conflict Found com.google.firebase:firebase-core:.11.0.4, but version 11.0.4 is needed

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play-services

The problem is I need Firebase version 11.0.4 but I have 11.0.4 ...

This is my build script

```
ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = '25.3.1'
    playServicesVersion = '11.0.4'
    firebaseVersion = '11.0.4'
}

dependencies {
compile project(":core")
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

// support libraries
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"

//play services
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$playServicesVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$playServicesVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$playServicesVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:$playServicesVersion"

compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:.$firebaseVersion"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$firebaseVersion"

.....
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Found com.google.firebase:firebase-core:.11.0.4, but version 11.0.4 is needed for the google-services plugin.**
:app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED
:app:processDebugGoogleServices (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 7,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

  > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.4.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

My google play service version is 43, sugestions?

Comment: Have you updated Google Repository to the latest version?

Comment: Google Repository is updated on version 57

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebaseVersion"
```

/* note: . is removed in above line */